# minimum cost to reach destination through tunnels

Tags: algorithm

Recently I faced a problem in the interview and not able to answer it. Any help will be appreciated.

Given a two dimensional grid *(1 <= **row** <= 10^9 && 1 <= **col** <= 10^9)* and starting and ending coordinates. we can only go to the four adjacent cells and it cost **1 unit**. we also have **N** tunnels *(1 <= N <= 200)* whose starting and ending coordinates are given and if we go through the tunnel it costs **k unit** *(1 <= k <= 10^9).*

**Note:** It is not necessary to take tunnels but if we take one it costs k unit of energy per tunnel taken.

we have to find the **minimum cost to reach the destination from the starting coordinate**.

starting coordinate *(1 <= sx, sy <= 10^9)*

destination coordinate *(1 <= fx, fy <= 10^9)*

Comment: Good problem statement but do you have a concrete question about a code attempt here? Please post a [mcve] or at least pseudocode/thought process, otherwise this is too broad. Examples of input/output with explanation are also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This is a cut and dried application of graph search, a simple algorithm is Dijkstra's, more complex but faster algorithm would be A*. If no suitable heuristic is known, you could try to preprocess the graph to form hierarchies with Dijkstra's. Typically contraction hierarchies are only useful with repeat queries, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies.

Comment: Not sure if it's that cut and dried. Grid is a billion^2 which is pretty big and I wonder if the tunnels might mess with the heuristic. I'm pretty rusty on this though.

Comment: @ggorlen yea, I see that now, in this case one needs to build a contraction of the original graph where the tunnels are nodes and are connected to each other by the shortest path to each other, as well as to the start and end node. Since there are only 200, the graph will have 202 nodes and 202 choose 2 edges. The edge weights will be the shortest path from each point-of-interest (either start/end/tunnel.) Then just run Dijkstra's on that, which gives the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem needs to be transposed into a graph with a weight given to each vertex. Once we have done that, we can use the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path.

Solving the problem thus boils down to transposing the problem into a graph with weighted vertices.

We can go from any cell to any other cell without going through a tunnel. The cost is then the manhattan distance. When the coordinate of a cell `c1` is `(x1,y1)` and another cell `c2` is `(x2,y2)`, the manhattan distance between `c1` and `c2` is `d=abs(x2-x1)+abs(y2-y1)`.

The nodes of the graph will correspond to the starting cell, the final cell, and every tunnel exit cells. The number of nodes in the graph is 2 + n where n is the number of tunnels.

There is a vertex between every node. The weight of a vertex to the final node is simply the manhattan distance. The weight of a vertex to a tunnel exit node is the manhattan distance to the tunnel entry cell plus the weight k associated to the tunnel.

This yields a graph that we can now solve using the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path.

Comment: so basically you are saying that we have n + 2 nodes, with one starting and one destination node and n nodes correspond to tunnel exit and then we have to form a complete graph(where edge weight is distance from that cell to opening of tunnel + k). Then we can apply Dijkstra to find the shortest path from starting cell to destination cell

Comment: @VipulVikram exactly. We’ll have (2+n)*(3+n)/2 -(2+n) = 1 + 3/2n + n²/2 vertices

Comment: @ggorlen oops, sorry, you are right. I’ll correct my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As [chmike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75517/chmike) mentioned, the question can first be transformed into a graph. Then Djikstra's algorithm for finding shortest paths can be used. Here's is my code -

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define int long long int

const int N = 402;
int dp[N][N];
pair<int,int> g[N];
int dist[N];
bool vis[N];

int32_t main(){
    int k,a,b,c,d,n,p,q,r,s,index,nodes,val;
    cin>>k>>a>>b>>c>>d>>n;
    index = 2;
    nodes = 2*n+1;
    for(int i=1;i<=nodes;i++)
        dist[i] = INT_MAX;
    memset(vis,false,sizeof(vis));
    memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
    for(int i=0;i<=nodes;i++)
        dp[i][i] = 0;
    g[0] = {a,b};
    g[1] = {c,d};
    dp[0][1] = dp[1][0] = abs(a-c)+abs(b-d);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>p>>q>>r>>s;
        dp[index][index+1] = k;
        dp[index+1][index] = k;
        g[index] = {p,q};
        g[index+1] = {r,s};
        for(int j=0;j<index;j++){
            val = abs(p-g[j].first)+abs(q-g[j].second);
            dp[j][index] = dp[index][j] = val;
            val = abs(r-g[j].first)+abs(s-g[j].second);
            dp[j][index+1] = dp[index+1][j] = val;
        }
        index += 2;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=nodes;i++){
        int v = -1;
        for(int j=0;j<=nodes;j++){
            if(!vis[j] && (v == -1 || dist[j] < dist[v]))
                v = j;
        }
        if(dist[v] == INT_MAX)
            break;
        vis[v] = true;
        for(int j=0;j<=nodes;j++)
            dist[j] = min(dist[j], dist[v]+dp[v][j]);
    }
    cout<<dist[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use dynamic programming

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define type long long

int main()
{ //k i sost of travelling through tunnel
//sx and sy are starting coordinates
//fx and fy are ending coordinates

//n are number of tunnels
    int k, sx, sy, fx ,fy,n;
    cin>>k>>sx>>sy>>fx>>fy>>n;
vector<vector<int>> arr(n, vector<int>(4,0));
map<pair<int, int> , pair<int,int>> mp;

//taking inputof tunnel elements and storing it in a map
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
             cin>>arr[i][j];

    pair<int,int> a,b;
    a= pair<int,int> (arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);
    b= pair<int, int> (arr[i][2], arr[i][3]);

    mp[a] = b;
    mp[b] =a;
    }//cin the elements

//function

vector<vector<type>> dp (fx+1, vector<type>(fy+1,LONG_LONG_MAX));
dp[fx][fy] =0; //end
for(int i= fx; i>=0; i--)
{
    for(int j= fy; j>=0; j--)
    {
        //go down
        if(j+1< fy)
        {
            dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j] , dp[i][j+1]+1 );
        }
       
        //go right
        if(i+1< fx)
        {
            dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j] , dp[i+1][j]+1 );
        }
        //tunnel
        if(mp.find(pair<int, int> (i,j))!= mp.end())
        {
            pair<int, int> temp= mp[pair<int, int> (i,j)];
            int a= temp.first, b= temp.second;

            if(dp[a][b]!= LONG_LONG_MAX)
            {
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j] , dp[a][b]+ k );
            }
        }
    }
}//

cout<<dp[sx][sy]<<'\n';

}
```

here i have used dp
the array dp is 2-d matrix that saves the cost to reach fx, fy.
we start from bottom up approach, at each cell we find the minimum cost to reach the end.

1. we check the cost to reach by stepping 1 cell downward i.e. from dp[i][j] to dp[i][j+1] .
2. then we check the right cell by dp[i+1][j]
3. we see if tunnel is present.